# How to use input or raw_input to create input to an OLS program

Tags: python, pandas, input, regression, raw-input

I want to create a little program that will allow me to use the `raw_input` (now just input) function in Python to input a group of numbers into a OLS function

Currently I have code that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.stats.api import ols

inp=raw_input("Enter String A")
A=map(int,inp.split())

inp=raw_input("Enter String B")
B=map(int,inp.split())

inp=raw_input("Enter String C")
C=map(int,inp.split())


def firstreg():

   df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[A], 'B':[B], 'C':[C]})
   reg = ols (y=df['A'], x=df[['B','C']])
   print reg

firstreg()
```

As you can see I was trying to use the `A=map(int,inp.split())` to fix my problem. It didn't work. I have also used `A=array(inp)` and `A=float(inp)` and `A=str(inp)` to try and fix my problem all with no avail. The main issue is that the OLS function is Pandas needs the input to be a string to work.

I would like to have the program run like this:

1. Run the file as regression.py
2. It asks for **Enter String A**
3. The user enters their group of numbers either as "1,2,3 ect..." or "1 2 3 ect..."
4. Then the user does the same for **Enter String B** and **Enter String C**.
5. Then the program prints out the regression results based on the OLS model in `def firstreg():`

I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue with this code is that you are nesting your lists of integers inside of another list on this line:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[A], 'B':[B], 'C':[C]})
```

What you are doing here is taking each of the lists you created above using the map function and then placing it inside another list. `[A]` for input string `"1 2 3"` will become `[[1, 2, 3]]` which is not what we want. Replace that line with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})
```

and it should work.

**EDIT:**

Written out in full:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas.stats.api import ols


def first_reg(A, B, C):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A, 'B': B, 'C': C})
    reg = ols(y=df['A'], x=df[['B', 'C']])
    print reg

def main():
    user_input = raw_input('Enter String A: ')
    A = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
    user_input = raw_input('Enter String B: ')
    B = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
    user_input = raw_input('Enter String C: ')
    C = [int(x) for x in user_input.split()]
    first_reg(A, B, C)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```